# Layering Text and Images on background video css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to recreate a cool look I saw on a graphic design mockup but I am unsure how to do it. There is a background video, with a transparent green overlay over it, then there is an image of a man that stays fixed to the right with text overflowing over it. For the most part I was able to recreate it but it still does not look right and the image does not stay fixed to the right side. Any suggestions or a different method would be appreciated.

Here is the mockup of the webpage I am trying to recreate in CSS:
[image: sample image]

Here is what I have managed to recreate using bootstrap:

```css
*::before, *, *::after{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  height: 70vh;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.jumbotron video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*  object-fit is not supported on IE  */
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(126, 154, 111, 0.5);
}

.jumbotron .container-fluid {
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.image-holder {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-holder img {
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  right: 0;
}

#heyGoodMeeting {
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 4;
}

.showcase__description {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <video autoplay muted loop>    
            <source src="https://geniecast.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Zuen-Office-Background-Video.mp4" data-src="" type="video/mp4">
            
        </video>
        
          <div class="container-fluid text-white d-flex justify-content-end">
            <div style="width: 80%">
                <img id="heyGoodMeeting" src="https://geniecast.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Good-Meeting-Logo.png" alt="hey good meeting">
                <div class="showcase__description">The personalized comedy event that will transform your next client gathering, holiday party, or company meeting from a typical zoom call into a customized, memorable, and hilarious experience.</div>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
            </div>
            <div class="image-holder">
                <img src="https://geniecast.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/David-Header.png" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.container -->
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a link to a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qgomwx8d/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in your jsfiddle demo, it seems like you didn't include Bootstrap 4 but you tagged Bootstrap 4 in your question.

To style that person picture in the background, you can just do the same way you did on the video and the overlay: set its position to absolute, top, bottom and right to 0 so that it sticks on the right. I think the tricky part is to set its height to 100% so that it won't overflow its parent relative container.

Anyway, I've cleaned up the layout a little bit and assigned several custom CSS classes so that I can style those classes instead of directly on the elements:

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid banner">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <video />
    <img src="https://geniecast.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/David-Header.png" 
      class="img-background" />
    <div class="banner-content container-fluid">
        <div class="showcase">
            <img id="heyGoodMeeting" 
              src="https://geniecast.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Good-Meeting-Logo.png" 
              class="img-fluid" />
            <p class="description" />
            <a class="btn btn-light btn-lg" />      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following is the CSS to stick that person picture in the background:

```css
.banner .img-background {
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/xd2s630q/80/